# Wikis on OS X Server - How do I include or embed content from one wiki page on another?

Tags: osx-server, server.app

How do I include or embed content from one wiki page on another in Wiki Server on OS X Server?
The other wiki page resides on the same server.

This is known as an "include", Redmine has it:

```
Include a wiki page. Example:
!{{include(Foo)}}
or to include a page of a specific project wiki:
!{{include(projectname:Foo)}}
```

MediaWiki has it under the name of "transclusion":
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Transclusion

Commercial wikis like Confluence have it:
https://wiki.mq.edu.au/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=79103996

**Edit:** The pages are in the same wiki, actually. I don't want external content, it's just that a lot of information in one page has to appear exactly in other pages.

Comment: Are all the wikis you want to cross link on the same server? (and if your server has more than one domain being served - are they on the same FQDN)?

Comment: The pages are in the same wiki, actually. I don't want external content, it's just that a lot of information in one page has to appear exactly in other pages. I think all wikis have it, wikipedia does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. To anyone running up the same wall I did... I switched to an OpenSource Ruby on Rails app called WAGN http://wagn.org

It does this exact thing and much more.

Answer (score 0):

**This is currently not possible in OS X Server wikis.** To include content from other pages, that content must be copy-pasted into the desired location—you can't reference text from other pages.

Comment: Really? I thought all wikis had this. Kind of useless if they don't. You can only create links that direct outwards so basically you can't create content, but only annotate your ideas on existing stuff that you get from somewhere else. Weird design decision! I can see wiki permissions have to be watched for stuff to transclude correctly but that could have been left to the user to sort out. There is this thing in the menu HTML snippet but it's not nearly as useful as transclusion.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit a page you see an arrow in tools bar that permit you to insert link (external or internal).
For the internal link don't copy/paste url, cause it'll doesn't work if you migrate your wiki to another server.
Just use wiki tools.

Comment: The question is talking about something else, transclusion *pulls* the content from another page, it's the "reverse" of linking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone else will run into this issue since this is an old post, but I was able to find out how to link to another page within a Mac server wiki. I know that doesn't solve embedding content, but at least for linking to another page:

1. Click the little backwards pointing arrow button that allows you to insert links.
2. Select "Search"
3. Type in the name of the wiki page you want to link to.
4. Select that page from the results of your search.
5. You now have a link to your other page.

When you click on the link button, the page you want may also show up under "Recents" if it is a page you have visited recently.